# Time Rules - a fraud case

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Agent J of Time Rules, a sub-division of the Bureau of Inter-temporal Fraud Force (BIFF) shook his head. Since 2041, when quantum computers had inadvertently created entanglement through time, rogue operators had tried to exploit the new found technology to transmit information through time, and in doing so disrupt the future, past and present. Anyway, his job, working through "messages" going backwards was getting tougher and tougher. Most of his hunts were wastes of time (whatever that meant nowadays?)

That being said there was something about these particular messages -after all the alleged recipient Al Macan was a very rich man:

Message 1 (Received 1957):  Brave abrasive engineer library
Message 2 (Received 1989):  Burger membrane frail celebration
Message 3 (Received 2005):  Capital sparks afraid charging

Agent J looked up at the sign over the door "Not on our watch" and stared at the messages again

Can you help Agent J - what do these messages mean - it's never too late